# Were there messengers to the People of the Book?

Tags: tafseer

> O People of the Scripture, there has come to you Our Messenger to make
> clear to you [the religion] after a period [of suspension] of
> messengers, lest you say, **"There came not to us any bringer of good
> tidings or a warner."** But there has come to you a bringer of good
> tidings and a warner. And Allah is over all things competent. ([5]
> Al-Ma'idah : 19)

Does this mean that there was no messenger to the people of the Book?

Comment: Both verses are pretty clear and there's nothing to reconcile since they don't oppose each other. They only show some claims of the people of the book.

Answer (score 0):

**There exist multiple claims here.**

**Claim-1:** According to the verse **5:19**,  IF prophet Muhammad(pbuh) had not been sent to the people of the Book THEN they would have had no warner AND they would have had a valid justification on the day of judment .

**Claim-2:** IF Claim-1 is true THEN self contradiction exist in the verse **5:19** where the people of the Book, by definition, had already warners before.

**Claim-3:** IF Claim-1 is true THEN contradiction exist with the verse 6:156 where the people of the Book would have no justification on the day of judgement

**Quran 5:19** O People of the Scripture, there has come to you Our Messenger to make clear to you [the religion] after a period [of suspension] of messengers, lest you say, "There came not to us any bringer of good tidings or a warner." But there has come to you a bringer of good tidings and a warner. And Allah is over all things competent.

**Quran 6:156** [We revealed it] lest you (Pagans) say, "The Scripture was only sent down to two groups before us, but we were of their study unaware" Or lest you say, "If only the Scripture had been revealed to us, we would have been better guided than they."

**RESPONSE:** here are the **corrected** claims, logically derived from the verses

**My Claim-1:** According to the verse **5:19**,  IF prophet Muhammad(pbuh) had not been sent to the people of the Book THEN they would have had no warner after a period of suspension of messangers AND they would have had a valid justification on the day of judgement .

**My Claim-2:** IF Claim-1 is true THEN no self contradiction exist in the verse **5:19** where the people of the Book, by definition, had already warners before the period of suspension.

**My Claim-3:** IF Claim-1 is true THEN no contradiction exist with the verse 6:156 where Pagans would have valid justification on the day of judgement, which only makes following sentence valid on the day of judgement:
"The Scripture was only sent down to two groups before us, but we were of their study unaware".
**As you see there is no justification of the people of the Book in this sentence.**

But lets force ourselves to interpret what justification of the people of Book might be. Assuming Quran was not revealed(Claim-1), Pagan here says if they had the Scripture similar to people of the Book, they would also be on the right path. This means that if the Quran was not revealed, the people of the Book would be on the right path (even with false beliefs) because they would have valid justification (no warner came to them after their anchestors corrupted the religion during the periof of suspension, no blame to later generations).

**Note that choosing the right path requires there to be a right path.** If there is no right path, both Pagans and People of the Book would have valid justification on the day of judgement. With Quran, there exist always a right path and such excuses are eliminated to the extend of personal capacity and situation.

**Quran 2:286 "Allah does not charge a soul except [with that within] its capacity..."**

Comment: Yes, before the Prophet, a messenger did not come to them for a long time. But they had the Torah and the Gospel in their hands. If they have the books of the Prophets Musa and Isa, how can they say on the Day of Judgment that a messenger was not sent to them?

Comment: Read my claim 1 again and focus on the period of suspension. Bible or Torah is given before the period of suspension. However, on the day of Judgement, they say no warner is sent to them after the period of suspension.  My Claim-1: According to the verse 5:19, IF prophet Muhammad(pbuh) had not been sent to the people of the Book THEN they would have had no warner after the period of suspension AND they would have had a valid justification on the day of judgement

Answer (score 0):

In Surah Al-Ma'idah (5:19), Allah says:

"O People of the Scripture, there has come to you Our Messenger making clear to you much of what you used to conceal of the Scripture and overlooking much. There has come to you from Allah a light and a clear Book."

And in Surah Al-An'am (6:156), Allah says:

"[We revealed it] lest you say, 'The Scripture was only sent down to two groups before us, but we were of their study unaware.'"

These verses can be reconciled by understanding that the first verse (5:19) refers to the Prophet Muhammad (peace be upon him) as the Messenger who came to the People of the Scripture (Jews and Christians). He brought a clear message and guidance from Allah, which included clarification of their previous scriptures.

The second verse (6:156) emphasizes that the Quran was revealed to the Prophet Muhammad (peace be upon him) so that people cannot claim that previous scriptures were only sent to specific groups, excluding others. It highlights the universality of the Quran and its message for all people.

Both verses emphasize the importance of the Quran as a clear and comprehensive book of guidance for all of humanity, and they do not contradict each other. They complement each other in emphasizing the universal nature of the Quran's message.

May Allah guide us all to the truth and grant us understanding.